# Arabic and french character with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, encoding, character-encoding

i have a from in jsp page which display arabic and french character correctly but when i put a word in arabic strange character in server side.

```
function saveQualite() {

alert($('#quality input').val() );
    // here it's ok it display me the right character 

$.ajax({
    url : 'saveQualite',
    data : { "quality" : $('#quality input').val() },
    [..]

}
```

here in Controller i got wrong character like `Ø£ØªÙ?ØªÙ?Ù?Ù?`

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "saveQualite")
    public @ResponseBody
    void saveQualite(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println("quality : "+request.getParameter("quality"));

}
```

Also a other problem when the page is load it display me the word `Qualité` correctly but after this line in ajax

```
        success : function(responce) {   
        $('#page_gestion').html("<div class=\"success\">Qualité enregistrée avec succées</div>");
```

It display me

```
Qualit� enregistr�e avec succ�es
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is resolved, for Arabic character it was a `hibernate` issue i have to edit my jdbc url like this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pagesjaunes?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

and also i have to set `type : 'post'` at ajax function.

For french character in ajax call i have to modify my js file type to `utf-8`, right click on js file in eclipse -> properities.
P.S after modification i have to check again my js file and fix wrong french character ;)

And if we want display Arabic character in eclipse console we choose utf-8 in run->run configuration... -> tomcat-> common.